# SSH to MySQL database in PythonAnywhere hangs indefinitely, SSH is correct, workbench can connect perfectly

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector, pythonanywhere, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL 8 database on PythonAnywhere with a python file. I have set up everything exactly as listed on [their help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/). I have a Premium account that allows external connections.

Using the same credentials I have connected MySQL Workbench to the database, and everything works correctly.
However using the same credentials from my script, with logging, just hangs on a single line. If I change anything like the username, password, port number etc to be incorrect then it realizes and raises an exception.

The full code is:

```
import mysql.connector
import sshtunnel
import logging
import sys

log_format = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(
    stream=sys.stdout, filemode="w", format=log_format, level=logging.DEBUG
)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.propagate = True

sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0

# SSH tunnel configuration
ssh_host = "ssh.pythonanywhere.com"
ssh_username = "my_pythonanywhere_username"
ssh_password = "my_pythonanywhere_password"

# Database configuration
db_host = "my_pythonanywhere_username.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com"
db_port = 3306
db_username = "my_pythonanywhere_username"
db_password = "my_password"

logger.info("Hello before tunnel")

# Establish SSH tunnel
try:
    with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host),  # , ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_username,
        ssh_password=ssh_password,
        remote_bind_address=(db_host, db_port),
    ) as tunnel:
        logger.info("Hello mid tunnel")
        db_config = {
            "user": db_username,
            "password": db_password,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": tunnel.local_bind_port,
        }
        logger.info(tunnel.local_bind_port)
        db = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)
        logger.info("Hello after tunnel")

        # Execute SQL command
        query = "SHOW DATABASES;"
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query)

        # Fetch and print the result
        databases = cursor.fetchall()
        for database in databases:
            print(database[0])

        # Close cursor and connection

except Exception as e:
    logger.error("An error occurred: %s", str(e))
finally:
    if "cursor" in locals() and cursor:
        cursor.close()
    if "db" in locals() and db:
        db.close()
    if "tunnel" in locals() and tunnel:
        tunnel.close()

logger.info("Hello end of file")
```

When I run this, I see "Hello before tunnel" and "Hello mid tunnel", but nothing further. Any errors in credentials and the try/except block catches it, and it prints the "Hello end of file" line.

The full list with log statements that gets printed when it hangs is:

```
INFO 2023-08-23 19:58:31,099 - Hello before tunnel
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,272 - starting thread (client mode): 0x9d33a440
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,273 - Local version/idstring: SSH-2.0-paramiko_3.3.1
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,376 - Remote version/idstring: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5
INFO 2023-08-23 19:58:31,376 - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_8.2p1)
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,474 - === Key exchange possibilities ===
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,474 - kex algos: curve25519-sha256, curve25519-sha256@libssh.org, ecdh-sha2-nistp256, ecdh-sha2-nistp384, ecdh-sha2-nistp521, diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, diffie-hellman-group16-sha512, diffie-hellman-group18-sha512, diffie-hellman-group14-sha256
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,474 - server key: rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256, ssh-rsa
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,474 - client encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,474 - server encrypt: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com, aes128-ctr, aes192-ctr, aes256-ctr, aes128-gcm@openssh.com, aes256-gcm@openssh.com
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,481 - client mac: umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha1
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,481 - server mac: umac-64-etm@openssh.com, umac-128-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com, hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com, umac-64@openssh.com, umac-128@openssh.com, hmac-sha2-256, hmac-sha2-512, hmac-sha1
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,483 - client compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,484 - server compress: none, zlib@openssh.com
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,485 - client lang: <none>
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,485 - server lang: <none>
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,486 - kex follows: False
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,487 - === Key exchange agreements ===
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,488 - Kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,489 - HostKey: rsa-sha2-512
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,489 - Cipher: aes128-ctr
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,490 - MAC: hmac-sha2-256
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,491 - Compression: none
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,491 - === End of kex handshake ===
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,601 - kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function openssl_sha256>
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,602 - Switch to new keys ...
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,603 - Got EXT_INFO: {'server-sig-algs': b'ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com'}
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,603 - Attempting password auth...
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:31,834 - userauth is OK
INFO 2023-08-23 19:58:31,957 - Auth banner: b'<<<<<<:>~ PythonAnywhere SSH. Help @ https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SSHAccess\n'
INFO 2023-08-23 19:58:31,972 - Authentication (password) successful!
INFO 2023-08-23 19:58:31,977 - Hello mid tunnel
INFO 2023-08-23 19:58:31,978 - 49493
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:32,020 - [chan 0] Max packet in: 32768 bytes
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:33,380 - Received global request "hostkeys-00@openssh.com"
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:33,380 - Rejecting "hostkeys-00@openssh.com" global request from server.
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:33,522 - [chan 0] Max packet out: 32768 bytes
DEBUG 2023-08-23 19:58:33,522 - Secsh channel 0 opened.
```

After printing that final line the program just hangs. Ctrl+C doesn't cause it to stop, only the bin seems to.

I'm using VSCode. I've tried running as administrator, no change. I've tried everything I can think of but I can't get any thing different to happen, other than errors. I've done what I can with the documentation but I'm pretty new to this, and I'm probably not making the most of the information in there.
I even tried ChatGPT, which suggested I "Consult with an Expert"...
The fact that it detects an incorrect database password tells e that the SSH and probably database connections are working correctly.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The difference I see between your code and what is provided on PythonAnywhere help page is that you use `mysql.connector` instead of `MySQLdb`, and your db connection (inside the tunnel) does not have the database name, something like `yourusername$database`.

Comment: According to PythonAnywhere it should be fine to use any MySQL library which is why I went with mysql connector. Hoewever it just doesn't work. I found if I changed to pymysql everything works fine. The only line to change in the code is:

`db = mysql.connector.connect(**db_config)` 
`db = pymysql.connect(**db_config)`

I also tried the same code using `MySQLdb` and again it all works perfectly. So it relates to `mysql.connector`. I can't find what about it is the problem, just a few forum posts elsewhere that describe  the same problem, and the same outcome. Thank you for your time :).

Comment: Cool, glad you got that working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved with the same solution as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65565172/python-mysql-connector-hangs-indefinitely-when-connecting-to-remote-mysql-via-ss) , `use_pure` is set to `False` by default, changing it to `True` gets the code working. It seems like the thing which is supposed to auto revert from `False` to `True` if the code has a problem isn't functioning.

The MySQL.connector documentation has more information [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-cext-development.html).